# Is it possible to load animated gif images?

Tags: animation, file-format

I have an animated gif and wanted to use it in the animation but I'm not sure how.

Comment: do you want to add a animated gif in to blender? Or just in part of the animation?

Comment: out of interest, how did you want to use the animated gif exactly? did you want to show it in the 3d view port? or did you want to apply it to a primitive like a plane, and have the animation rendered out as part of your render?

Answer (score 8):

Short answer:

**You can't.**

Blender does not support the gif format.

Long answer:

You would need some other software to convert your gifs to a format that blender understands to be able to import them.

For a list of supported formats see [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/media/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is this plugin: https://github.com/doakey3/bligify

I was not able to get it to work, but maybe it would work for others.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your animated gif into a video, or start with video in the first place, and use that as a texture.

It can be a little problematic if you wanted some transparency, in which case you also need to make a video of the mask you want to animate.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem recently, I used an [Online Converter](https://ezgif.com/gif-to-sprite) to a sprite-sheet. I chose to put all frames in a single column:

[image]

For width and height I specified just the GIF's width and height, to be sure they are constant regardless of the area being redrawn by the frame.

Then I made this node setup:

[image]

The lowest, left, red *"Value"* input node is where you have to specify the number of frames (in my case it's `12`).

In material settings, I've set the *Blend Mode* to **Alpha Blend**:

[image]